# Matlab - How to customize the xaxis with datetime values in a grouped bar graph?

Tags: matlab, datetime, plot, bar-chart, graphic

How can I customize the xaxis for a grouped bar graph with datetime values:

I have a 150x3 matrice as my y-values and a vector of 150x1 datetimevalues in format dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss. Each group of bars schould be labeled with one datetime value on the xaxis, as you can see in the picture: The [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IuiX.png)

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
clc; clear all; close all; 
figure;
y = [1 3 5; 3 2 7; 3 4 2];
b = bar(y,'FaceColor','flat');
d1 = '23-Aug-2010 16:35:42';
t1 = datetime(d1,'InputFormat','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
d2 = '24-Aug-2010 16:35:42';
t2 = datetime(d2,'InputFormat','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
d3 = '25-Aug-2010 16:35:42';
t3 = datetime(d3,'InputFormat','dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss');
x = [1 2 3];
str = {datestr(t1); datestr(t2); datestr(t3)};
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',str, 'XTick',1:numel(str));
xtickangle(45);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
    figure;
    y = [1 3 5; 3 2 7; 3 4 2];
    b = bar(y,'FaceColor','flat');
    x = [1 2 3];
    str = {'alpha'; 'beta'; 'gamma'};
    set(gca, 'XTickLabel',str, 'XTick',1:numel(str))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Nash for your answer. Could you give me an example with a vector of datetime values on the xaxis as in my question? Thank you in advance

Comment: See another answer as it is difficult to format the code in the comments in here.